# Unexpected token "=>"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I get this error on console **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'** on line 7 when trying to run this:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve('Hello World');
const promise2 = 10;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Goodbye'));
let promise4 = fetch
('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res
=>
    res.json()
);
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4])
.then(
    values => 
    console.log(values)
);
```

Can someone help me out?

*Im a total newbie to JS.*

Comment: Line 7 is syntax error -> no linebreak before =>

Comment: Place the `=>` on the same line as `res`. `=>` generally has to go on the same line as the parameters.

Comment: what code formatter are you using, you need to place `=>` in same line as res,something like this  `.then(res=>res.json());`

Comment: placing  `=>` on the same line as `res` works but traversy media put it on the next line and still got it to work (https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/658239125232680974/726797077148991558/unknown.png?width=887&height=499) why doesnt it work for me?

Comment: @MasrurSakib It's not on the next line of code in that picture. That's word wrap.